# How to automatically stop Sagemaker notebook instances if it is idle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-sagemaker, lifecycle

I have been looking for a script to automatically close Sagemaker Notebook Instances that have been forgotten to be closed or that are idle. A few scripts I found don't work very well (eg: [link](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle) , it is only checking if ipynb file is live, Im not using .ipynb, or taking the last updated info which never changes until you shut down or open the instance)
Is there a resource or script you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to find idle instances. You can modify the script to stop the instance if idle for more than 5 minutes or have a cron job to stop the instance.

```
import boto3

last_modified_threshold = 5 * 60
sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
response = sm_client.list_notebook_instances()

for item in response['NotebookInstances']:
    last_modified_seconds = item['LastModifiedTime'].timestamp()
    last_modified_minutes = last_modified_seconds/60
    print(last_modified_minutes)
    if last_modified_minutes &gt; last_modified_threshold:
        print('Notebook {0} has been idle for more than {1} minutes'.format(item['NotebookInstanceName'], last_modified_threshold/60))
```

Comment: Hi Leon, Thank you for your response.
I've seen this script before, but I didn't choose to use it because item['LastModifiedTime'] output never changes until you open or close the notebook instance. Even If I give like 1 hr, this script may cause shutdown the instance while I am actively using it. Am I approaching it wrong aspect?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click *Edit* on your Notebook Instance Setting.
2. Create new *Lifecycle config*
3. Paste [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/on-start.sh) in it.
4. You can change the idle time on `IDLE_TIME` constant.